# Math operations within HTML

Tags: html, math

Is it possible to perform math operations within HTML, like `<div width="50/2">`?
Or can this only be done using Javascript or CSS?

Comment: No. HTML is not a "programing" language. It has no math capabilities like that. CSS has some basic number stuff, but nothing like actually acting like a calculator. you'll have to use JS.

Comment: And why do you need it? Unless you have variables?

Comment: Jinja can help you: [Perform arithmetic operation in Jinja2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56536767/perform-arithmetic-operation-in-jinja2)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, Html and css can not perform math operations.
You can do this in javascript. But if you have choice you should not do perform complex math operations with javascript unless you know javascript well. Because javascript has some weird behaviour for example:

```
document.write(.1 + .2)  // 0.3000000000000004  (instead of 0.3)
document.write(.3 + .6)  // 0.8999999999999999  (instead of 0.9)
```

But as long as you are dealing with integer values you should be fine. 
Or if you want to deal with decimals in javascript just convert them to integer (by multiplying with 100 and then convert back the result into decimal by divinding by 100.)

You can use other languages along with html and css on server side:

- php
- python
- java
- ruby
- javascrript (both server and client side)

which can do all the math and much more.

But if you are computing layout features for example making calculation for width and height to add in css then I guess you should just use javascript. But read a little about its unexpected behavior with decimals. So you don't get wrong result.

Answer (score 0):

No.  You will have to use javascript to compute the width and then update the attribute to the correct element in the DOM.