# Perform arithmetic operation in Jinja2

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

I want to find the difference between two different values. But, I am getting a `Jinja2` error. I am not sure about how to find the difference in this template.

I tried using `-` operator but this did not work. So, I used `sub` to find the difference between actual and predicted score.

```
 {% for e in question.essays %}
    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">
            <h3 class="panel-title">{{loop.index}}</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="panel-body">
            <div class="actual-score">Actual score: {% if e.actual_score %} {{e.actual_score|round(1)}}/5{% endif %}</div>
            <div class="predicted-score">Predicted score: {% if e.predicted_score %}{{e.predicted_score|round(1)}}/5{% endif %}</div>
            <p class="essay-text">Text: {{e.text}}</p>
        <div class="diff">Difference: {{ e.actual_score|sub(e.predicted_score)}} </div>

        </div>
```

I am getting this error:

```
TemplateAssertionError: no filter named 'sub'
```

Comment: Is your `sub` referring to `<sub>` tag?

Comment: No, I used it to perform subtraction but found that jinja does not have default sub as filter. Now how can I find the difference

Comment: Have tried simply  `{{ e.actual_score - (e.predicted_score)}}`?

Answer (score 6):

According to the [Jinja2 documentation](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/2.10/templates/#math), using `-` should work pretty fine. Also from my end, it is working just fine. Mind posting the error message you get when using the operator. I also cannot find the `sub` tag in the documentation for Jinja2.

Therefore, as [Amazing Things Around You](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9396051/amazing-things-around-you) has said, I think this should work:

```
{{ e.actual_score - e.predicted_score }}
```

Just a side note, the only other template tag I have found that does arithmetic operations close to that is [Django's add tag](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/2.10/templates/#math), which also does not do subtraction.

Comment: TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'float' and 'NoneType'

I got this error while using {{ e.actual_score - e.predicted_score }}

Comment: Looks like you're trying to perform a subtraction between a number and ```None```. You need to have a numeric value in order to perform subtractions