# How do I perform arithmetic operation on a templated type using Jinja2?

Tags: python-3.x, jinja2

I am trying to perform arithmetic operations on a templated `datetime` value using Jinja2. I looked at the following question: [Perform arithmetic operation in Jinja2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56536767/perform-arithmetic-operation-in-jinja2) and I see that Jinja2 has support for performing arithmetic on templated types.
I want to extend this to `datetime`.

I tried doing this:

```py
from jinja2 import Template
import datetime
template = Template("Date: {{ currentDate +2  }}")
template.render(currentDate=datetime.datetime.today())
```

but it throws the following:

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'datetime.datetime' and 'int'
```

I tried thinking of a solution where I can assign a function that, when invoked, returns the date in number of days since the epoch but I still need to be able to represent that value as a valid date.
How do I achieve this using Jinja2?

Comment: Well you cannot do that in Python either, what would `now+2` even means? Is it two seconds or minutes or days or months or years from now?

Comment: It is number of days.

Answer (score 3):

Since your goal is to add two days to another date, you could pass the `datetime` module to the template, then use its [`timedelta()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#timedelta-objects) method:

Given:

```py
from jinja2 import Template
import datetime

template = Template("""
Date:        {{ currentDate }}
In two days: {{ currentDate + datetime.timedelta(days=2) }}
""")
print(
    template.render(
        currentDate=datetime.datetime.today(), 
        datetime=datetime
    )
)
```

This would yield:

```
Date:        2023-01-10 19:52:50.276999
In two days: 2023-01-12 19:52:50.276999
```

---

You could even simplify the code further to

```py
from jinja2 import Template
import datetime

template = Template("""
Date:        {{ datetime.datetime.today() }}
In two days: {{ datetime.datetime.today() + datetime.timedelta(days=2) }}
""")
print(
    template.render(datetime=datetime)
)
```

But remember that a templating system is meant to do the display and you should refrain from doing too much logic in a template.
So, you have to draw the line somewhere between what amount of logic is acceptable in the templates and what is not.

For example, in a [MVC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller), you would probably rather do:

```py
from jinja2 import Template
import datetime

now = datetime.datetime.today()
template = Template("""
Date:        {{ now }}
In two days: {{ in_two_days }}
""")
print(
    template.render(
        now=now,
        in_two_days=now + datetime.timedelta(days=2)
    )
)
```